# InfluxDB: No Data in UI After Python Script Write

Tags: python, docker, influxdb

I’m encountering an issue with writing data to an InfluxDB instance running in a Docker container ( (influxdb:latest) on another machine within my local network. I’m using the InfluxDB Python client.

I can access the InfluxDB UI through a web browser at http://ip_other_machine:8086, so network connectivity seems fine.

Here’s the Python script I’m using to write data:

```
from datetime import datetime
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient, Point, WritePrecision

InfluxDB credentials and details
influxdb_host = ‘http://ip_other_machine:8086’
token = ‘TOKEN’
org = ‘My_ORG’
bucket = ‘MY_BUCKET’

Initialize InfluxDB client
with InfluxDBClient(url=influxdb_host, token=token, org=org) as client:
write_api = client.write_api()

# Create a Point structure
point = Point("test_measurement") \
    .tag("location", "test_location") \
    .field("value", 123.45) \
    .time(datetime.utcnow(), WritePrecision.NS)

# Write data to InfluxDB
try:
    write_api.write(bucket=bucket, record=point)
    print("Data sent to InfluxDB successfully.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error sending to InfluxDB: {e}")
```

The script executes without errors and indicates “Data sent to InfluxDB successfully.”

However, when I check the InfluxDB UI, no data appears.

I’ve confirmed that the token used has write permissions for the bucket ‘[MY_BUCKET]’.
I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong and would appreciate any insights or suggestions!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the scrip to:

```
import influxdb_client
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS

# Your specific details
influxdb_host = 'http://10.1.100.126:8086'
token = 'MY_TOKEN'
org = 'MY_ORG'
bucket = 'MY_BUCKET'

# Initialize the InfluxDB client
client = influxdb_client.InfluxDBClient(
    url=influxdb_host,
    token=token,
    org=org
)

# Create the write API
write_api = client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)

# Create a line in InfluxDB Line Protocol
line = "my_measurement,location=Prague temperature=25.3"

# Write data
write_api.write(bucket=bucket, org=org, record=line)
```

No idea why the first script didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the timerange of the UI?

I had similar problems, and the error was a result of a wrong timestamp given by Python. Maybe you try to not send the timestamp. Then the timestamp is automatically the actual time. Check if this data will appear.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
after testing with Postman, i changed the python script to something similar to the logic displayed at the node.js documentation and it worked.